# Visual Studio 2012 does not recognize html tags

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, clr, javascript-intellisense

I'm getting this when openning any web project,

[image: Error on html recognition]

Some clues could be:

- something wrong with _references.js
- I'm getting this messages on DEBUG:

> 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 2):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll'
>   cargado. El módulo se compiló sin símbolos. Primera excepción del tipo
>   'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' en mscorlib.dll 'iisexpress.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll' cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll' cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir. Primera
>   excepción del tipo 'System.Security.SecurityException' en mscorlib.dll
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll' cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir. Primera
>   excepción del tipo 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' en mscorlib.dll
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime\v4.0_12.3.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Users\Credesa\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\9a56cdc0\b8d4b9ba\App_global.asax.3e2myxit.dll' cargado. 
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Users\Credesa\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\9a56cdc0\b8d4b9ba\assembly\dl3\519ddeb7\25fde096_5a05d101\Application.dll'
>   cargado. Símbolos cargados. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml.Hosting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Xaml.Hosting.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Users\Credesa\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\9a56cdc0\b8d4b9ba\assembly\dl3\66b83a45\9fec8a8c_31f9d001\AjaxControlToolkit.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Users\Credesa\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\9a56cdc0\b8d4b9ba\assembly\dl3\14074e54\1cfaeb9d_9fe9d001\EntityFramework.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Users\Credesa\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\9a56cdc0\b8d4b9ba\assembly\dl3\02a36887\2d21ec9d_9fe9d001\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Users\Credesa\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\9a56cdc0\b8d4b9ba\assembly\dl3\6a862e25\ca650e59_bcf9d001\EPPlus.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.resources.dll'
>   cargado. El módulo se compiló sin símbolos. Primera excepción del tipo
>   'System.Web.HttpException' en System.Web.dll Primera excepción del
>   tipo 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' en
>   System.Web.dll 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Tracing\v4.0_12.3.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Tracing.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'A_5a0f4b02_6ed9_497e_a42f_572e71fb5929' cargado.  'iisexpress.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Services.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Services.Design.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089\System.resources.dll'
>   cargado. El módulo se compiló sin símbolos. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Users\Credesa\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\9a56cdc0\b8d4b9ba\App_Web_webform1.aspx.cdcab7d2.z12ikt4b.dll'
>   cargado.  'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.HtmlParser\v4.0_12.3.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.HtmlParser.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir. Primera
>   excepción del tipo 'System.Web.HttpException' en System.Web.dll
>   Primera excepción del tipo
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' en System.Web.dll
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Web.Entity.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Design.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Design.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Users\Credesa\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\9a56cdc0\b8d4b9ba\App_Web_site.master.cdcab7d2.ngimtes0.dll'
>   cargado.  'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Users\Credesa\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\9a56cdc0\b8d4b9ba\App_Web_home.aspx.cdcab7d2.lwb7qrfu.dll'
>   cargado.  'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'
>   cargado. No se encuentra el archivo PDB o no se puede abrir.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/24/ROOT-1-130891750994008527):
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.resources.dll'
>   cargado. El módulo se compiló sin símbolos. El subproceso 0x1f6c
>   terminó con código 259 (0x103). El subproceso 0x16bc terminó con
>   código 259 (0x103).

Answer (score 0):

Solved only formatting and re-installing everything...